# Kotlin generics with in produces Type mismatch when compiling

Tags: kotlin

I´m working on a code with generics and when I use an `in` I got a TypeMismatch when compiling.

The code is the following:

```
open class A
class B:A()

data class DataContainer(val a:String,
                         val b:A)

interface Repo<T:A>{
    fun setParam(param:T)
    fun getParam():T
}
abstract class RepoImp<T:A>:Repo<T>{
    private lateinit var parameter:T
    override fun setParam(param: T) {
        parameter = param
    }

    override fun getParam(): T {
        return parameter
    }
}
class BRepo:RepoImp<B>()

class Repo2(val repo: Repo<in A>){

    fun process(b:DataContainer){
        repo.setParam(b.b)
    }
}

val repoB = BRepo()

val repo2 = Repo2(repoB)// Here I got: Type mismatch: inferred type is BRepo but Repo<in A> was expected
```

I also tried changing the attribute repo from Repo2 to Repo<*>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BRepo is a `Repo<B>`, it is not a `Repo<in A>`, (but it would satisfy `Repo<out A>`).

In other words, a `Repo<in A>` must be able to accept `setParam(A())`, but `BRepo.setParam()` can only accept a B or subclass of B.

Or to put it another way, `BRepo` is a `Repo<B>`, which is a tighter restriction on the type than `Repo<A>` when it comes to writing values (but looser restriction when reading values).

The reason `class Repo2(val repo: Repo<*>)` doesn't work is that `Repo<*>` is essentially a `Repo<in Nothing/out A>`. You can't call `setParam()` on a `Repo<*>` with any kind of object.

There's a design flaw in your code that you can't fix simply by changing Repo2's constructor signature. As it stands now, Repo2 needs to be able write A's to the object you pass to it, and a BRepo by definition does not support writing A's, only B's. You will need to make at least one of your class's definitions more flexible about types.

It might be easier to understand the covariance limitation with more common classes:

```
val stringList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
var anyList: MutableList<in Any> = ArrayList()
anyList.add(5)  // ok
anyList = stringList // Compiler error. 
                     // You wouldn't be able to call add(5) on an ArrayList<String>
```

Basically `MutableList<String>` is not a `MutableList<in Any>` the same way `Repo<B>` is not a `Repo<in A>`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Repo2` class expect to consume only type `A`, use `Repo2<T : A>(val repo: Repo<in T>)`

```
open class A
class B : A()
class C : A()
class D : A()

class BRepo : RepoImp<B>()
class CRepo : RepoImp<C>()
class DRepo : RepoImp<D>()

interface Repo<T : A> {
    fun setParam(param: T)
    fun getParam(): T
}

abstract class RepoImp<T : A> : Repo<T> {
    private lateinit var parameter: T
    override fun setParam(param: T) {
        parameter = param
    }

    override fun getParam(): T {
        return parameter
    }
}

class Repo2<T : A>(val repo: Repo<in T>) {

    fun process(b: DataContainer<T>) {
        repo.setParam(b.b)
    }
}

data class DataContainer<T : A>(
    val a: String,
    val b: T
)

fun main() {

    val repoB = BRepo()
    val repoC = CRepo()
    val repoD = DRepo()

    val repo2 = Repo2(repoB)
    val repo3 = Repo2(repoC)
    val repo4 = Repo2(repoD)

    repo2.process(DataContainer("Process B type", B()))
    repo3.process(DataContainer("Process C type", C()))
    repo4.process(DataContainer("Process D type", D()))

    println(repo2.repo.getParam())
    println(repo3.repo.getParam())
    println(repo4.repo.getParam())

}
```